# IOS Development don't open Instagram App by cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Tags: ios, cordova, instagram

I'm developing an app by cordova using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing to share contents to socials.

All work fine for many socials, but not for Instagram.

I use this function but I'm strongly sure that the problem is not here but on backend

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaInstagram(
    'Text to share', //textToShare, 
    'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png',
    function(result)    {console.log("Sharing success");}, 
    function(errorMsg)  {console.log("Sharing failed with message: " + errorMsg);}
);
```

info.plist is configured as:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>facebook</string>
    <string>facebook-stories</string>
    <string>mailto</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>instagram-stories</string>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

My xcode console write these messages:

```
Only support loading options for CKShare and SWY types.

error fetching item for URL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FB7A9D6-4D57-418E-92D2-4A897DEF5747/tmp/instagram.igo : (null)

error fetching file provider domain for URL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FB7A9D6-4D57-418E-92D2-4A897DEF5747/tmp/instagram.igo : (null)

Collaboration: error loading metadata for documentURL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FB7A9D6-4D57-418E-92D2-4A897DEF5747/tmp/instagram.igo error:Error Domain=NSFileProviderInternalErrorDomain Code=0 "No valid file provider found from URL file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FB7A9D6-4D57-418E-92D2-4A897DEF5747/tmp/instagram.igo." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No valid file provider found from URL file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1FB7A9D6-4D57-418E-92D2-4A897DEF5747/tmp/instagram.igo.}
```

Any suggestion?